# How to put two columns in the same line with Listbox C#

Tags: c#

I trying to put firstname and lastname in the same line but without success, instead this return firstname, lastname value in list.
What I'm doing wrong?

```
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
           this.lstBoxRunnerName.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
           dr["firstName"].ToString() , dr["lastName"].ToString(),
        });

        }
```

Comment: `lstBoxRunnerName.Items.Add($"{dr["firstName"].ToString()} {dr["lastName"].ToString()}");`

Comment: A listbox doesn't have columns. You need a different control, or concatenate the values into a single string. `AddRange` adds multiple *individual* items, it doesn't create columns

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think OP meant `DataRow` columns.

Comment: I think he that columns mean from DataRow

Comment: Winforms or WPF?

Comment: @itsme86 Thanks, for the help, it fit in my code perfectly ( > . < )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For single item use `Add`, not `AddRange`

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
   this.lstBoxRunnerName.Items.Add(dr["firstName"].ToString() + dr["lastName"].ToString());
}
```